# PHP: How to handle $_POST data

Tags: php, post, netbeans

I'm getting a warning on netbeans when using this code. Could someone post code that won't show any warning in netbeans and achieves what I want. Does my code contain a security flaw?

.

The warning I'm getting says "Never directly access Superglobal $_POST. Use some filtering function instead."

.

```
<?php
//test if required vars are set
if (
    isset($_POST['num']) &&
    isset($_POST['desc'])
) {
    (double) $num = filter_var($_POST['num'], FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_FLOAT, FILTER_FLAG_ALLOW_FRACTION);
    $desc = $_POST['desc'];

    //do stuff after with these vars such as: mysqli queries; equations with ! === || &&. 
}
?>
```

Comment: Netbeans is complaining about this line: `$desc = $_POST['desc'];`. This isn't, of itself, insecure, but what you do with it might be. Netbeans is simply reminding you to treat user data with considerable circumspection.

Comment: @MikeW The OP will actually get them in all 4 lines where they are used :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use this:

```
<?php

if (filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'num') && filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'desc')) {
    (double) $num = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'num', FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_FLOAT, FILTER_FLAG_ALLOW_FRACTION);

    $desc = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'desc');

    //do stuff after with these vars such as: mysqli queries; equations with ! === || &&. 
}
```

Comment: Your first two lines - the `isset` - will lead to a fatal error: `Can't use function return value in write context`. `filter_input` returns `NULL` if the variable name is not set, so you could test for that instead.

Comment: So the isset() isn't needed in the example above?

Comment: @compsci, Yes, it will return `NULL` if var doesn't exist

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't worry too much about that warning, even the line where you actually use a filter function (although a different one than NetBeans suggests...) generates that same message.

These are hints that should make you think about what you are doing and they can be very useful.

However, if you don't want to see them, you can go to:

```
Tools > Options > Editor > Hints
```

And turn specific warnings off individually.